# Hide element when AutoCompleteTextView gain focus

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I have 3 `AutoCompleteTextView` and I want to make a simple function to detect whenever it gain/loses focus so I'll hide an `imageView`.

Or maybe, whenever the keyboard is UP I want to hide my logo (imageView). When the keyboard is down, show the imageView again.

Code so far:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        for(int i=0; i< layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
            if(v instanceof AutoCompleteTextView) {
                v.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
//                        if(hasWindowFocus()) {
//                            ImageView logo = findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
//                            logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pimba", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
```

Also, is it possible to create `listeners` outside this `onCreate()` ? Or creating everything inside this function is the right way to go?

Comment: can you tell your basic requirement or need ?what you actually wanna do ?

Comment: Whenever I focus the EditText / Open the keyboard, I want to hide de logo (imageView). So whenever I hide the keyboard the logo appears again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> **Solution 1**

Call this method in `onCreate()`

```
private void initKeyBoardListener() {
  //Threshold for minimal keyboard height.
    final int MIN_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_PX = 150;
    //Top-level window decor view.
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Register global layout listener.
    decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        // Retrieve visible rectangle inside window.
        private final Rect windowVisibleDisplayFrame = new Rect();
        private int lastVisibleDecorViewHeight;

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(windowVisibleDisplayFrame);
            final int visibleDecorViewHeight = windowVisibleDisplayFrame.height();

            if (lastVisibleDecorViewHeight != 0) {
                if (lastVisibleDecorViewHeight > visibleDecorViewHeight + MIN_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_PX) {
                    Log.d("Keyboard", "SHOW");
                    // Hide imageview
                } else if (lastVisibleDecorViewHeight + MIN_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_PX < visibleDecorViewHeight) {
                    // Show imageview
                    Log.d("Keyboard", "HIDE");
                }
            }
            // Save current decor view height for the next call.
            lastVisibleDecorViewHeight = visibleDecorViewHeight;
        }
    });
}
```

> Solution 2

Use this Util class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Raman on 2/10/2017.
 */
public class KeyboardUtils implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    private static HashMap<SoftKeyboardToggleListener, KeyboardUtils> sListenerMap = new HashMap<>();
    private SoftKeyboardToggleListener mCallback;
    private View mRootView;
    private float mScreenDensity = 1;
    private KeyboardUtils(Activity act, SoftKeyboardToggleListener listener) {
        mCallback = listener;

        mRootView = ((ViewGroup) act.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
        mRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        mScreenDensity = act.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }

    public static void addKeyboardToggleListener(Activity act, SoftKeyboardToggleListener listener) {
        removeKeyboardToggleListener(listener);

        sListenerMap.put(listener, new KeyboardUtils(act, listener));
    }

    public static void removeKeyboardToggleListener(SoftKeyboardToggleListener listener) {
        if (sListenerMap.containsKey(listener)) {
            KeyboardUtils k = sListenerMap.get(listener);
            k.removeListener();

            sListenerMap.remove(listener);
        }
    }

    public static void removeAllKeyboardToggleListeners() {
        for (SoftKeyboardToggleListener l : sListenerMap.keySet())
            sListenerMap.get(l).removeListener();

        sListenerMap.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
        mRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

        int heightDiff = mRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
        float dp = heightDiff / mScreenDensity;

        if (mCallback != null)
            mCallback.onToggleSoftKeyboard(dp > 200);
    }

    private void removeListener() {
        mCallback = null;

        mRootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }

    public interface SoftKeyboardToggleListener {
        void onToggleSoftKeyboard(boolean isVisible);
    }

}
```

And its usage
Call this in `onCreate()`

```
KeyboardUtils.addKeyboardToggleListener(getActivity(), new KeyboardUtils.SoftKeyboardToggleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onToggleSoftKeyboard(boolean isVisible) {
                Log.d("keyboard", "keyboard visible: " + isVisible);
                if (!isVisible) {
                   // show imageview
                }
                else 
                  {
                  // hide imageview
                    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But nothing is happening when I open/close the keyboard.

Comment: check my answer now , try the other solution

Comment: Android Studio is offering me if I want to create a getter, import a method and some other stuff on `getActivity()` -> `KeyboardUtils.addKeyboardToggleListener(getActivity(), ...`. If I use `this`, the app crashes on startup :P

Comment: are you using in fragment or activity ?

Comment: what is the crash ?